# Calculate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\log\binom{n}{k}}{n^2}$

Tags: combinatorics, limits

How to prove if the following limit exists?

If it exists, what's the value?

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\log\binom{n}{k}}{n^2}$$

Thanks!

Comment: What is your work on the subject ?

Comment: I just saw this in another community. I thought it interested and tried to work it out by myself, but finally I had to turn here for help...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Notice that we can write

$$ \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \log \binom{n}{k} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left( \frac{2k-1}{n} - 1 \right) \log\left(\frac{k}{n}\right). $$

Taking $n \to \infty$, this converges to the integral

$$ \int_{0}^{1} (2x-1)\log x \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2}. $$

Comment: [+1] Excellent! I just obtained the same value using Stirling approximation. Confirmed also by numerical simulation.

Comment: @JeanMarie, Thank you!

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why $\dfrac{1}{n}\log{\binom{k}{n}} = \left(\dfrac{2k-1}{n}-1\right)\log\left(\dfrac{k}{n}\right)$? I wonder why do you substitute binomial coefficient with fraction.

Comment: @Ramil, Your computation is pretty close to what I have done there. Notice that the sum above equals $$ \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \(2k - 1 - n) \log k = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \(2k - 1 - n) \log \left(\frac{k}{n}\right) + \frac{\log n}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \(2k - 1 - n). $$ Computation shows that the latter sum vanishes, hence yields the identity.

Comment: For improper integrals, the convergence of Riemann sums is not automatic, but it seems to be OK here.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1744250/convergence-of-riemann-sums-for-improper-integrals for example.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks! Your solution is correct indeed, I found a mistake in my computations.

Comment: @Barry Cipra, I agree that it required elaboration. If we are forced to use only preliminary level of analysis, justification step may be pesky. Otherwise, we can simply appeal to the dominated convergence theorem together with the estimate $$ \left| \sum_{k=1}^n \left( \frac{2k-1}{n} - 1 \right) \log\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) \mathbf{1}_{(\frac{k-1}{n}, \frac{k}{n}]}(x) \right| \leq \left| \log x \right| $$ valid for $x \in (0, 1]$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've learned a lot.

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\ln\pars{n \choose k} \over n^{2}} & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}
{\sum_{k = 1}^{n + 1}\ln\pars{n + 1 \choose k} -
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\ln\pars{n \choose k} \over \pars{n + 1}^{2} - n^{2}} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}
{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\ln\pars{{n + 1 \choose k}/{n \choose k}} \over 2n + 1}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\,\lim_{n \to \infty}
{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\bracks{\ln\pars{n + 1} - \ln\pars{n - k + 1}} \over n + 1/2}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\,\lim_{n \to \infty}{n\ln\pars{n + 1} - \ln\pars{n!} \over n + 1/2}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\,\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{\vphantom{\Large A}%
\pars{n + 1}\ln\pars{n + 2} - n\ln\pars{n + 1} - \ln\pars{n + 1}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{\pars{n + 1}\ln\pars{1 + 2/n \over 1 + 1/n}} =
\bbx{1 \over 2}
\end{align}

Comment: I realized I could use Stolz theorem twice and solved it easily several hours after I posted the question... Thank you all the same.

Comment: @Maristie Thanks. When I saw the $@\texttt{Sangchul Lee}$ answer, I thought Stoltz-Ces$\mathrm{\grave{a}}$ro (SC) doesn't work because  $@\texttt{Sangchul Lee}$ didn't use it. However, after awhile I realized that SC indeed works very fine.

Comment: I admit that I am weak at utilizing Cesaro-Stolz theorem. Nice solution! (+1)

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks. Indeed, I believe you are quite strong.