# $a_n = (1- (\frac{1}{n})^\alpha ) ( 1-(\frac{2}{n})^\alpha)......(1-(\frac{n-1}{n})^\alpha )$ and $n\ge 2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

determine for  which  value  $\alpha $ the  sequence

$a_n = (1- (\frac{1}{n})^\alpha ) ( 1-(\frac{2}{n})^\alpha)......(1-(\frac{n-1}{n})^\alpha )$  and $n\ge 2$ converges

i think when  $\alpha = 0 $ definitely  it   will converges  to   $ o$

afterthat   when  $\alpha \neq 0$  then    what   happen.??? as   i can not able to proceed further.....................................................................

pliz  help  me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\alpha>0$,
\begin{align*}
\log a_{n}=\dfrac{(1/n)\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\log\left(1-(k/n)^{\alpha}\right)}{1/n},
\end{align*}
we see that
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\log(1-(k/n)^{\alpha})\rightarrow\int_{0}^{1}\log(1-x^{\alpha})dx<0,
\end{align*}
so $\log a_{n}\rightarrow-\infty$, so $a_{n}\rightarrow 0$.

Now consider $\alpha<0$, write $\alpha=-p$, $p>0$, we first deal with $(-1)^{n}a_{n}$, then 
\begin{align*}
\log(-1)^{n}a_{n}=\dfrac{(1/n)\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\log\left(1/(k/n)^{p}-1\right)}{1/n},
\end{align*}
we see that
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\log(1/(k/n)^{p}-1)\rightarrow\int_{0}^{1}\log\left(\dfrac{1}{x^{p}}-1\right)>0,
\end{align*}
so $\log(-1)^{n}a_{n}\rightarrow\infty$ and hence $(-1)^{n}a_{n}\rightarrow\infty$. If it were $a_{n}\rightarrow L$ for some real number $L$, then $(-1)^{2k}a_{2k}\rightarrow L$, a contradiction.

Comment: im not getting the  last line,,,If it were $a_{n}\rightarrow L$ for some real number $L$, then $(-1)^{2k}a_{2k}\rightarrow L$, a contradiction....can u elaborate  more

Comment: Because $((-1)^{2k}a_{2k})=(a_{2k})$ which is a subsequence of $(a_{n})$, must have the same limit point, so $(-1)^{2k}a_{2k}\rightarrow L$, but we have on the other hand that $(-1)^{2k}a_{2k}\rightarrow\infty$ as a subsequence of $((-1)^{n}a_{n})$.

Comment: that  mean  at$ \alpha = -1  $ it will  diverges,,, tell  me  now  the  value  of $ \alpha $,,at  which sequence will converges..

Comment: Then only $\alpha=0$ goes through.

Comment: that mean the given sequence ${a_n}$ converges  only at $ \alpha  = 0$..Am i right ??

Comment: thanks   a lots  @user284331

Comment: Sorry, for that $\alpha>0$, the sequence also converges, the limit is zero. So for all $\alpha\geq 0$, the sequence converges.

Comment: @user284331 In your proof you use the fact that \begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\log(1-(k/n)^{\alpha})\rightarrow\int_{0}^{1}\log(1-x^{\alpha})dx<0,
\end{align*} But this is not so obvious. What is indeed TRUE is that \begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(k/n)\rightarrow\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx,
\end{align*} provided that $f$ is CONTINUOUS in $[0,1]$ . Unfortunately, $\log(1-x^a)$ is NOT continuous. Not even bounded!

Comment: Yes, that is wrong?

Comment: @user284331 You should show it!

Comment: Ah... I missed that, but intuitively, because $\alpha>0$ and $x\in[0,1)$, the function $\log(1-x^{\alpha})$ has only negative sign, and it is improper integrable, things should be not that bad, but let me think how to properly fill in the details.

Comment: Fortunately, this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1744250/convergence-of-riemann-sums-for-improper-integrals) addresses this issue.