# Asymptotic formula for $\sum_{k=0}^n f(k)g(n-k)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

Of course this assumes $f,g$ both positive functions are sufficiently well behaved, and part of the question is to find criteria for any asymptotic formula to be valid. Also, the formula is symmetric, since

$$\sum_{k=0}^n f(k)g(n-k)=\frac{1}{2}\Big[\sum_{k=0}^n \Big(f(k)g(n-k)+f(n-k)g(k)\Big)\Big].$$

In a number of cases, I've found that

$$\sum_{k=0}^n f(k)g(n-k)\sim nf(n)g(n)\int_0^1 f(x)g(1-x)dx.$$

This seems to be true if $f(k)=g(k)=k^\alpha$ assuming $k>0$, $f(0)=g(0)=0, \mbox{ and }\alpha > -1$. If $f(k)=g(k) =1/k$ then the sum is asymptotically equal to $(2 \log n)/n$.

Can you prove the asymptotic formula? If not correct, what is the asymptotic behavior of the sum? What are the conditions on $f,g$ for the formula to hold? Can it be generalized to functions not meeting these criteria?

**Update**

I think my formula might be correct for a large class of rational functions, and even some algebraic function. For instance, if $f(k)=g(k)=\sqrt{k}$, I computed the sum using $10^5$ terms and it gives the approximation $0.39266908 \times n^2$. The constant is correct up to $8$ digits. Its exact value according to my formula, is $\frac{\pi}{8}$.

More surprisingly, with $f(k)=g(k)=1/\sqrt{k}$, we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k(n-k)}} \rightarrow C.$$

The constant $C$ computed using $10^5$ terms is about $3.132357$. The exact value if my formula is correct is $\pi$. Convergence is very slow this time, but by increasing the number of terms, I get closer, albeit very slowly, to $\pi$. Is $C$ really equal to $\pi$? An answer to that question, either proving or disproving this fact, will be accepted as an answer to my question.

Comment: It’s not clear how in general the convolution will be bounded using the values in $[0,1].$ The relationship between the values in $[0,1]$ and the integer values are essentially unrelated.

Comment: If $f(n)=g(n)=a^n,$ then the convolution is $na^n$ and $$nf(n)g(n)\int_0^1=ana^{2n}.$$ You might be close if $f,g$ are polynomials.

Comment: Only tangentially related, but if $$  f(n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} g(n-k) \cdot f(k) $$ then
 $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(n) x^n = Exp( \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} g(k) \frac{x^k}{k} )  $$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Riemann sums and utilizing the beta function, $$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1} {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {k(n - k)} }}}  = \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1} {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {(k/n)(1 - k/n)} }}}  \to \int_0^1 {\frac{{dx}}{{\sqrt {x(1 - x)} }}}  = B\left( {\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2}} \right) = \pi .
$$
In general, if your $f$ and $g$ have the property that
$$
\frac{{f(x)}}{{f(y)}} = f\!\left( {\frac{x}{y}} \right),\quad \frac{{g(x)}}{{g(y)}} = g\!\left( {\frac{x}{y}} \right)
$$
(e.g., $f$ and $g$ are multiplicative) then
$$
\frac{1}{{nf(n)g(n)}}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {f(k)g(n - k)}  = \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {f\!\left( {\frac{k}{n}} \right)\! g\!\left( {1 - \frac{k}{n}} \right)}  \to \int_0^1 {f(x)g(1 - x)dx} ,
$$
provided $x \mapsto f(x)g(1-x)$ is Riemann integrable on $(0,1)$.

Comment: As a comment,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 1 n \sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1}
 \frac 1 {\sqrt {\frac k n \left( 1 - \frac k n \right)}} =
\int_0^1 \frac {dx} {\sqrt {x (1 - x)}}$$
is true but needs to be proved, in general Riemann sums do not converge to the value of the improper integral.

Comment: @Maxim You are right, I should have mentioned it. Here is a proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1745876