# If we can't Stieltjes integrate Brownian motion pathwise, then what do the values of the Ito integral represent?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

The Ito integral strongly resembles the Stieltjes integral (in either Lebesgue or Riemann flavor), to the point that I would almost want to define $(\int_\text{Ito}X \, dM)(\omega)$ as the Stieltjes integral $\int X(\omega) \, dM(\omega)$. The problem of course is that when $M$ is the sort of stochastic process we're interested in, $M(\omega)$ is almost always a function of unbounded variation.

The construction of the Ito integral somehow gets around this by defining itself on the entire probability space all at once, rather than trying to do it pointwise at each $\omega$. But where exactly the magic happens is mysterious to me. At the end of the construction, we somehow end up with a value $I(X,M)(\omega)$. If not the Stieltjes integral of $X$ against $M$, then what *is* that value? What does it represent?

The whole thing reminds me conditional expectation.  We can't define conditional expectation at a point because we'd be trying to condition on an event of measure zero, but if we instead define it on *the entire space all at once*, via a kind of global property (it should integrate to something appropriate) then we make sense of the problem. Is something similar happening here?

I found this quote on a related question that sounds appealing but I don't know exactly what it means: *"...you get the integral evaluated as a limit of sums over partitions converges in probability."* ([source](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/426789/30481)).

Comment: The Itô integral reduces to the Stieltjes integral when the integrator is of bounded variation (barring pathological cases I haven't thought of right this moment), so there has to be something about requiring a weaker notion of convergence for the Riemann sums...

Comment: You might be interested in rough paths, which give a way to "make arbitrary decisions" that allow you to interpret stochastic integrals in a pathwise sense.

Comment: This question is also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2055402/36150

Answer (score 10):

Let $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a Brownian motion. Let's forget for the moment everything we already know about stochastic integrals and start at the very beginning of the story:

We would like to define a stochastic integral $\int \dots \, dB_r$ with respect to Brownian motion. Which properties do we expect the stochastic integral to have?

- **Wish Nr. 1:** The stochastic integral should be an additive mapping, i.e. $$\int_0^t (G(r)+H(r)) \, dB_r = \int_0^t G(r) \, dB_r + \int_0^t H(r) \, dB_r$$ whenever we can make sense of the integrals.
- **Wish Nr. 2:** We would like to have $$\int_0^t dB_r = B_t-B_0$$.
- **Wish Nr. 3:** .... is some sort of pull out property. If a random variable $\xi$ does not depend on the values of $(B_r)_{r > s}$, then $$\int_s^t \xi \, dB_r = \xi \int_s^t \, dB_r$$ ("pull out what is known").

If we combine these three properties, we find that the stochastic integral of a simple function of the form

$$H(r,\omega) = \sum_{j=1}^n \xi_j(\omega) 1_{[t_{j-1},t_j)}(r)$$

(where $t_0< \ldots < t_n \leq T$ and $\xi_j$ is $\mathcal{F}_{t_{j-1}}$-measurable) is given by

$$\int_0^T H(r) \, dB_r = \sum_{j=1}^n \xi_j (B_{t_j}-B_{t_{j-1}}) = \sum_{j=1}^n H(t_{j-1}) (B_{t_j}-B_{t_{j-1}}). \tag{2}$$

So far all the integrals can be interpreted as pointwise ($\omega$-wise) integrals, and, moreover, we have a nice interpretation for the integrals.

**The bad news:** Defining the stochastic integral

$$\int_0^t H(r) \, dB_r$$

as a pointwise limit of Riemann sums of the form $(2)$ works only for a very small class of integrands $H$; this is closely related to the fact that the Brownian motion has almost surely unbounded variation (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2055518/36150) for more details). For instance if $H:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous mapping, we cannot expect that the limit of the Riemann sums

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^n H((j-1)/n) (B_{j/n} -B_{(j-1)/n})$$

exists with probability $1$.

**The good news:**  We can simply consider a different type of convergence. Almost sure convergence of a sequence is a pretty strong assumption, and therefore it is quite natural to consider weaker forms of convergence. The most natural choice is clearly convergence in probability (or, alternatively, convergence in $L^2$). It turns out that the limit the Riemann sums converge very nicely in probability, and this allows us to define the stochastic integral for a large class of integrands. Some nice things about this definition:

- Almost sure convergence implies convergence in probability. This means that if we have an integrand $H$ for which the integral $\int_0^t H(r) \, dB_r$ can be defined pathwise as the limit of Riemann sums, then both notions coincide.
- If $(H_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a continuous adapted process, then $$\sum_{j=1}^n H(t_{j-1}) (B_{t_j}-B_{t_{j-1}}) \stackrel{n \to \infty}{\to} \int_0^t H(r) \, dB_r \quad \text{in probability}$$ for any sequence $\Pi_n = \{0=t_0 < \ldots < t_n = t\}$ of partitions of $[0,t]$ with mesh size converging to $0$. Note that this implies in particular that there exist a subsequence which converges almost surely.
- The same construction works for a much larger class of driving processes; for instance we can easily replace $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ by a martingale with continuous sample paths.

I hope that this answer gave you some insight why

... Riemann sums pop up in the Itô theory although the Itô integral is not defined as a Riemann integral  (namely, because we want to have $(2)$ for simple functions)

... there is nothing magic about it. Pointwise convergence does not work, but by considering a weaker form of convergence we can get rid of this problem and obtain a nice stochastic calculus for a large class of integrands.

Comment: Does integration wrt a Brownian motion work when we want convergence of the Riemann sums in $L^2$? Or I guess, more generally, is there a theory of stochastic integration where the sense of convergence is in $L^2$, instead of in probability?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist Actually, it's the other way round: Since $L^2$-convergence implies convergence in probability, the more general definition is obtained by considering convergence in probability.(In the $L^2$-framework typically somewhat stronger integrability assumptions are needed.)

Comment: yes, I understand that $L^2$ (and a.s.) convergence imply convergence in probability. Do you have any references for the $L^2$-framework I could look at?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist I like the monograph by René Schilling ("Brownian Motion - An Introduction to Stochastic processes") quite a lot; he considers stochastic integration with respect to Brownian motion (in the $L^2$ framework).

Comment: @saz In your "pull out property", is $\xi$ a stochastic process, or just a real random variable?

Comment: @JackM $\xi$ is a random variable.

Comment: If we only have $L^2$ convergence in general, in what sense can we expect to have these processes describe something in nature? I would usually think that if we have some stochastic process, $X : \Omega \to C[0,1]$, 'nature' picks an element $\omega$ from the state space and what we observe is $X(\omega)$. I'd like to understand Ito integration in the same way: a sample path of Brownian motion (and maybe some other randomness) chosen by nature creates the process that we observe. Doing so would require a pathwise interpretation. Maybe there is something wrong with this physical intuition?

Comment: @Lorenzo If you are interested in physical interpretation, you can take a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/145680/36150). From my (mathematical) point of view, it doesn't make sense to consider fixed $\omega$ because the stochastic integral is simply no pointwise integral.

Comment: @saz I think one can phrase this concern as a purely mathematical question, in terms of whether we can expect simulations of the process (written as an Ito integral) to 'converge' to the true process. The computer picks a random seed, which is a lot like fixing $\omega$. I must admit that this confuses me a lot: maybe in some sense the only thing we observe / compute about the process are evaluations against $L^2$ continuous functionals?

Comment: @Lorenzo I don't understand what you mean by "simulations of the process converging to the true process". Obviously, this depends on how you simulate the process....

Comment: @saz Sorry for the confusion: the only simulation method I am (sort of) familiar with is Euler-Maruyama.

Comment: @saz: What does mean "integrate pathwise" ? It's not clear the concept behind ? Thank you.

Comment: @user657324 Pathwise integration means that you fix $\omega \in \Omega$ and then define $\int_0^t H(s,\omega) \, dX_s(\omega)$ as in the deterministic setting, typically as a Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral. This approach doesn't work for Brownian motion.

Comment: So it's "pointwise" and not "pathwise", no ? @saz

Comment: @user657324 Well, if you prefer, you can call it "pointwise". The "point" is the fixed $\omega \in \Omega$ but to define the integral we actually use the path $t \mapsto X_t(\omega)$ of a stochastic process... so both words ("pointwise" and "pathwise") are appropriate, I think.